# Spring Data JDBC How to persist one-to-many collection nested inside another one-to-many relationship

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am having problem cascading persist operation on a collection of entities nested inside another child entity of an aggregate root. In other words I am trying to associate a collection of entities with an entity which is already on `many` end of a one-to-many relationship.

I have an aggregate root called `UniversalRecord` which contains a list of `Reservation` which  again contains a list of `Segment` objects.

```
data class UniversalRecord(
  val locatorCode: String,
  val reservations: Set<Reservation>
) {
  @Id var id: UUID? = null
}


data class Reservation(
  val locatorCode: String,
  val providerCode: String,
  val providerLocatorCode: String
  val createdDate: String,
  val modifiedDate: String,
  val cancelled: Boolean = false,
  val segments: Set<SegmentRef>
) {
  @Id @Column("UNIVERSAL_RECORD") var id: UUID? = null
}

@Table("reservation_segment_ref")
data class SegmentRef(val key: String) {
  @Id @Column("RESERVATION") var id: UUID? = null
}
```

But when I introduce another collection in Reservation entity i.e. List it fails.

Here is the sql:

```
CREATE TABLE universal_record(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    locator_code VARCHAR UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reservation(
    universal_record UUID,
    locator_code VARCHAR,
    provider_code VARCHAR(2),
    provider_locator_code VARCHAR,
    created_date DATETIME,
    modified_date DATETIME,
    cancelled BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE reservation_segment_ref(
    reservation UUID,
    segment UUID
);
```

Spring Data JDBC can save the entities contained in the aggregate root and link child entities to parent with generated key, fails when I add another list in the child entity with this error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't obtain a required id value`

Is it possible what I am trying to achieve? or do I need to convert Reservation as an aggregate root as well?

Thanks

Comment: I have an ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> which generates UUID for root before save operation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible what I am trying to achieve?

To be honest I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve.

But there is a problem with your current mapping.
The ID of `Reservation` collides with the back reference needed in the database from `RESERVATION` to `UNIVERSAL_RECORD`.
These should be two separate fields in the database, which together form a primary key for `RESERVATION`.
Of course it would be ok to make the id itself unique if you prefer that.

If you use UUID as id field you have to create the UUID as you already do for your aggregate root.
In the case of non root entities this should happen in the event listener for the root that you already use to set the id of the aggregate root.

Finally if you have single references, `List` or `Map` elements in an entity those entities don't need a dedicated ID and in my honest opinion they shouldn't have one, since the primary key gets constructed from the ID of the aggregate root plus in the case of `List` and `Map` a column holding the index/key.